# Can I convert a numpy function into a tensorflow function?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, tensorflow, gradient-descent

My target is to minimize a variable function `f(x1, x2,..., xn)`, and it involves a lot of complex computation. So I used scipy.numpy package to write `f(x)` and minimize it with `scipy.optimize.minimize()`. But it takes almost 4~5 hrs to minimize `f(x)`, which is TOO slow. To improve its speed, I intend to use gpu. And it is required `tensorflow`, which is not as convenient as `numpy`. Thus, I define a function below to convert a `numpy` function into a `tensorflow` function.

Take a simple example:

```
def f(x):
    return np.sin(x)

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 6)
X = tf.Variable(x, dtype=tf.float32)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    def tff(X):  # function in tensorflow
        x = X.eval()
        func = f(x)
        result = tf.convert_to_tensor(func)
        return result

    result = tff(X)
    sess.run(result)
```

Everything goes well until I add these lines:

```
  optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
  training_op = optimizer.minimize(tff(X))

  iteration = 1000
  for i in range(iteration):
      sess.run(training_op)
  best_X = X.eval()
  print(best_X)
```

It crashed... and showed the error below:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables
```

So can I convert `numpy` function into `tensorflow` function and use `GradientDescentOptimizer`? If not, what can I do to improve my optimizing speed without rewriting the function as `tensorflow` format?

BTW, I run my code on `google colab` so I needn't download `tensorflow` package on my computer.

Comment: That doesn't work, what you are doing is getting a value out of TensorFlow, doing some NumPy computation with it, and then creating a new constant tensor in TensorFlow. From the point of view of TensorFlow, `X` and `result` are completely independent tensors. In order to be able to minimize `result` for `X` (and therefore compute gradients) you have to rewrite your function `f` using TensorFlow functions instead of NumPy. There is no automatic way to do the conversion.

Comment: You could look at something like [JAX](https://github.com/google/jax), which allows you to compute gradients with NumPy, like [autograd](https://github.com/HIPS/autograd), but also can JIT-compile things to run on GPU. I have personally never used it, though, so I can't tell if it would really solve your problem or how easy or hard it would be to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your numpy function into tensorflow function a simple function is following. Make an IOU function in numpy and then call it via `tf.numpy_function`[here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function)

```py
def IOU(Pred, GT, NumClasses, ClassNames):
    ClassIOU=np.zeros(NumClasses)#Vector that Contain IOU per class
    ClassWeight=np.zeros(NumClasses)#Vector that Contain Number of pixel per class Predicted U Ground true (Union for this class)
    for i in range(NumClasses): # Go over all classes
        Intersection=np.float32(np.sum((Pred==GT)*(GT==i)))# Calculate class intersection
        Union=np.sum(GT==i)+np.sum(Pred==i)-Intersection # Calculate class Union
        if Union>0:
            ClassIOU[i]=Intersection/Union# Calculate intesection over union
            ClassWeight[i]=Union
            
    # b/c we will only take the mean over classes that are actually present in the GT
    present_classes = np.unique(GT) 
    mean_IOU = np.mean(ClassIOU[present_classes])
    # append it in final results
    ClassNames = np.append(ClassNames, 'Mean')
    ClassIOU = np.append(ClassIOU, mean_IOU)
    ClassWeight = np.append(ClassWeight, np.sum(ClassWeight))
    
    return mean_IOU
# an now call as
NumClasses=6
ClassNames=['Background', 'Class_1', 'Class_1',
            'Class_1 ', 'Class_1', 'Class_1 ']
x = tf.numpy_function(Strict_IOU, [y_pred, y_true, NumClasses, ClassNames], 
                        tf.float64, name=None)
```